# Inconsistency with @ManagedProperty

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces, managed-property, apache-tomee

i have a bean with a list of global data in @ApplicationScoped like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ManagedBean
public class GlobalData
{
  private List data = new ArrayList();

  //getter and setterss goes here.. 

  public void addSomeData(Object item) { data.add(item); }
}
```

also i have a @ViewScoped bean that references GlobalData through a @ManagedProperty like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SomePageController
{
   @ManagedProperty(value="#{globalData}"
   private GlobalData theGlobalData;
   //also public getter and setter of theGlobalData
}
```

the funny thing comes when in SomePageController i want to add an item to the list of GlobalData like this:

```
public void someUIAction()
{
    SomeItem item = bussinesProcess();
    theGlobalData.addSomeData( item );
}
```

because each time someUIAction is called, theGlobalData points to a totally new instance with an empty data!!!! i can confirm this because i added some loggin info like this:

```
public void someUIAction()
{
    SomeItem item = bussinesProcess();
    theGlobalData.addSomeData( item );
    System.out.println(theGlobalData.toString());
}
```

and then i got the following output:

```
com.myproyect.beans.GlobalData@3c76da81
com.myproyect.beans.GlobalData@19c1818a
com.myproyect.beans.GlobalData@9a7jp79c
......
```

a new instance on every request, i googled but the only information i could get is with [this guy](https://community.jboss.org/thread/199148?start=0&tstart=0) with a similar problem, still i also tried he's solution with no luck =(.

** aditional info**:
 im developing with TomEE 1.5.2 web profile wich includes Apache MyFaces 
 also i checked that all the anotations are from the javax.faces.bean package

Answer (score 1):

That will happen if you have imported `@ApplicationScoped` annotation from the wrong package, such as CDI's `javax.enterprise.context`, which is what most IDEs suggest as 1st autocomplete option. As you're managing beans by JSF's `@ManagedBean`, then you need to make sure that you also use a managed bean scope from the same bean management API.

```
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
```

When a JSF managed bean doesn't have a valid annotation definied, then it defaults to `@NoneScoped` which is in this particular case indeed a brand new instance on every EL-resolution, such as `@ManagedProperty`.

Comment: added a +1 since its a fairly common error but i just chequed all the anontations and they are all from the javax.faces.bean package, honestly i was hoping that this was the cause...=S